# Writing a scope for associations - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Could one kindly advise me how i can turn the below method into a scope.

- I want to be able to display all the events the user has paid to attend
- currently i can check in the views for an event if the user has paid to attend the event `@event.current_user_attending_paid?(@user)`
- The aim is to look for the events that have payments that belong to a specific user

i am finding this challenging. would it be something like this: `scope :booked_events, -> { joins(:payments).where(payment.user_id: user) }` in the event.rb file?

event.rb

```
has_many :payments

#checks if current user has paid to attend event
  def current_user_attending_paid?(user)
    self.payments.exists?(user: user)
  end
```

payment.rb

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end
```

user.rb

```
has_many :payments
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost solve this challenge in your attempt. In `event.rb`

```
scope :booked_events, -> (user) { joins(payments: :user).where(users: { id: user.id }) }
```

Comment: thank you @MikeDiet - could you please kindl help me with this question from the link: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485381/writing-a-scope-for-multiple-associations-rails-4`

Answer (score 1):

### Payment.rb

```
  scope :paid?, -> (user, event) { where(user_id: user.id, event_id: event.id) }
```

This returns an active record collect ActiveRecord::Relation object

Now in views, you can use like `Payment.paid?(User.first, Event.first).exists?`

```
exists? returns false if result is empty.
```