# Writing a scope for multiple associations - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having challenges writing a scope to display:

- all cards belonging to events that have payments that belong to a specific user
- i am currently able to display, all events that have payments that belong to a specific user using the scope `scope :booked_events, -> (user) { joins(payments: :user).where(users: { id: user.id }) }` in the event.rb file
- some events have a card and some don't

> could one kindly advise me how i display all events with a card that
>   have payments that belong to a specific user

event.rb

```
has_many :payments 
has_one :card
scope :booked_events_with_cards, -> (user) { joins(payments: :user).where(users: { id: user.id }) }
```

card.rb

```
belongs_to :event
```

payment.rb

```
belongs_to :event
belongs_to :user
```

user.rb

```
has_many :payments
```

i tried the below in the card.rb file but i am unsure

```
belongs_to :event
has_many :payments, through: :event
scope :cards_belonging_to_booked_events, -> (user) { joins(payments: :event).where(users: { id: user.id }) }
```

but got the below error:

```
2.3.0 :012 >   cards.cards_belonging_to_booked_events(user)
  Card Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "cards".* FROM "cards" INNER JOIN "events" ON "events"."id" = "cards"."event_id" INNER JOIN "payments" ON "payments"."event_id" = "events"."id" INNER JOIN "events" "events_payments" ON "events_payments"."id" = "payments"."event_id" WHERE "users"."id" = 4
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.id: SELECT "cards".* FROM "cards" INNER JOIN "events" ON "events"."id" = "cards"."event_id" INNER JOIN "payments" ON "payments"."event_id" = "events"."id" INNER JOIN "events" "events_payments" ON "events_payments"."id" = "payments"."event_id" WHERE "users"."id" = 4
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.id: SELECT "cards".* FROM "cards" INNER JOIN "events" ON "events"."id" = "cards"."event_id" INNER JOIN "payments" ON "payments"."event_id" = "events"."id" INNER JOIN "events" "events_payments" ON "events_payments"."id" = "payments"."event_id" WHERE "users"."id" = 4
```

or, am i to write the scope in event.rb file if i want to display all cards with events that have payments that have been made by a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to include `card` association in `joins`. It removes events without card associated from the query result:

```
scope :booked_events_with_cards, -> (user) { joins(:card, payments: :user).where(users: { id: user.id }) }
```

Comment: thank you @MikeDiet! i didn't realise you could add more than two objects(models). Could you recommend a good resource for learning to write scope (SQL queries).

Comment: Sure @ARTLoe first of all you need to read.. rails guide! xD http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: thank you @MikDiet! this is awesome! - i just figured out how to write the scope for `cards_belonging_to_booked_events ` in my question, due to having spending some time reading the resource you recommended and understanding your answers to my questions - thank you! thank you!